# Tips for interpretation stack trace, invalid comparison of objects (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, object, stack-trace

I'm currently interning for a software role and trying to get better with debugging and reading stack traces and was wondering if I could get some input/tips with an exception/bug I am getting.

I'm currently getting an error with some software (GUI interface) that basically throws an exception when I try to sort the folder view/list view by the "Size" column (farthest right column in image below) by clicking on that column header. The stack trace looks like its saying it can't compare an "ASString" object with an "ASSort" data object, which looks like those objects get passed as parameters into an ".CompareTo(Object x, Object y)" method.
[image]

I just wanted to make sure I was reading the stack trace correctly by reading the top-most exception, which seems to be the one saying that it's comparing invalid objects. Which makes me think I need to fix some casting somewhere in the source code where the .CompareTo(Object x, Object y) method is called.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't see the images but it's also possible that it's trying to sort on the wrong column.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 and can/am using the debugger via attaching a process.

Comment: I think you're reading the stack trace correctly.  The question, then, is why it's trying to compare a "sort" type to a "value" type.  I don't think the problem is a cast; typically casts are reversible.  There might be a problem with the way a comparer delegate or object is created.

Comment: *"GUI interface"*.  A Graphical User Interface interface?  I suppose you also enter your PIN number into an ATM machine. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far, and funny joke jmcihinney. I'm still struggling to find this bug, and it's a companies code and I kinda don't even understand what the majority of the code is doing since its calling other functions/interface/classes and stuff. Uh oh :(